# Нет панели работы с файлами в PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Как добавить такую панель в пайчарм?
[image: Панель для работы]

[image: Скриншот окна PyCharm]

Comment: какую именно панель? мы не можем залезть в твою голову и понять, что тебе нужно. А так обычно все делается в настройках. Что помешало тебе поискать там?

Comment: Панель где run и тому подобное, я пытался найти но что-то не получается

Answer (score 0):

Дважды нажимаешь shift, в поле ищешь main menu. View> Appearance> Navigation Bar[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь изложить словами, и использовать картинку только как дополнение. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].